# Unable to login into WordPress blog added to my existing PHP website

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a blog into my existing PHP website. So I installed WordPress using softaculous apps installer. WordPress installation finished successfully. But when I try to login into WordPress dashboard through wp-admin login panel using the correct username and password then login fails. There is no error message shown. The login page simply reloads and the Textboxes are reset. I have tried to reset my password by clicking in the lost password link. But unfortunately there is got no email in my registered email address. I have used .htaccess file in my exiting php website to remove .php extension. Here the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# skip POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Have you try to remove the .htaccess file and login again. ?

Comment: By default there is no .htaccess file in the WordPress subdirectory. I have added a .htaccess for this subdirectory using ftp and the problem is resolved.